# Mocking dependency of module/function under test in Javascript

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, testing, redux

Let's say I want to test the following for example:

```
import {fetchResourceFromBackend} from './myfetch';

const fetchSomething = (dispatch) => {

  dispatch(2);

  return fetchResourceFromBackend('/api/abc').then( result => {
    dispatch(3);
  });
};
```

`fetchResourceFromBackend` is some complicated function. How can I test this, and not be affected by `fetchResourceFromBackend` code (any pattern or tool recommendations, I use `mocha` and `sinon` but cannot achieve)?

Is my only option to provide `fetchResourceFromBackend` as an argument to `fetchSomething` so I can mock it?

Comment: You can mock it with jest: `jest.mock('./myfetch')` https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/manual-mocks.html

Comment: I'll try now, this seems like something I need. Don't know why someone down-voted, I think the question is legit.

Comment: Thanks! I used your suggestion and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Using *jest* as @Mikhail suggested I solved like this:

```
// test/something-test.js

import {myFetch} from '../_mocks_/utilities';

jest.doMock('modules/utilities', () =>({
    myFetch: myFetch
}));


const {fetchSomething} = require('modules/something');

describe('#fetchSomething', ...
```

Here `fetchSomething` is function under test that has internal dependency on `myFetch` function from `'modules/utilities'`. I mock that dependency with `myFetch` from `'../_mocks_/utilities'`.