# Jest - Mock Nested Function

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, jestjs

I am writing a JEST/Enzyme test case for module.

One of the function I am testing in my component is about saving an xml file. Which in turn calls a library function fileDownload from 'react-file-download'

```
const saveContentToXML = () => {
    if(this.props.message && this.props.message.details){
        fileDownload(this.props.message.details, this.props.message.title);
    }
}
```

When I wrote test case, it calls saveContentToXML and in turn calls fileDownload. This results in exception.

```
TypeError: window.URL.createObjectURL is not a function
```

My test case looks like

```
test('Save Content as XML Test', () =>{
    const component = shallow(<Message details={details} />);
    component.instance().saveContentToXML();
});
```

How do I test this function?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45325081/mocking-dependency-of-module-function-under-test-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You should mock react-file-download and then assert that it is being called

```
// Default mock will just make fileDownload a jest mock function
jest.mock('react-file-download')

import fileDownload from 'react-file-download'

test('Save Content as XML Test', () =>{
    const component = shallow(<Message details={details} />);
    component.instance().saveContentToXML();
    expect(fileDownload).toHaveBeenCalledWith('details', 'title');
    fileDownload.mockClear() // resets the mock function so the call is not used in assertions for other tests
});
```

The jest documentation on mock functions is a good resource to refer to: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/mock-functions.html